# LINQ: String.Join a list but add a character to that string beforehand

Tags: c#, linq, list, string, concatenation

I have the following list:

- alpha
- beta
- charlie
- delta

I want to turn these strings into one string, comma separated, but I want to add a character to them first (the @ symbol). The end result should be: `@alpha,@beta,@charlie,@delta`

What I have right now is a non-LINQ method, but it doesn't seem "clean":

```
String.Concat("@", String.Join(",@", mylist));
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
string.Join(",", mylist.Select(s => "@" + s));
```

Comment: This is a lot less efficient than OP's String.Concat since it needs to build a new string (and GC it) for every element in the list in addition to the string building done by string.Join.